# Find Properties of Polygons from Path2D, derived from the.to_planar() function of Trimesh Module in Python

Tags: python, polygon, stl-format, trimesh

With the Trimesh module in Python, I am able to get 2D cross-sections from a STL file, with the code shown below.

```
mesh = trimesh.load_mesh('MyFile.stl')
slicex = mesh.section(plane_origin=mesh.centroid, plane_normal=[0,30,0])
slice_2D, to_3D = slice.to_planar()
```

With the 2D Path (Slice_2D), obtained from the above code, I am able to get the polygons in it as a NumPy array and iterate over it with the code below:

```
for polygon in slice_2D.polygons_closed:
    trimesh.path.polygons.plot_polygon(polygon, show=True)
```

The above code SHOWS the polygons on the console. However, I would like to know if there is a way to get the properties of the polygon, for example: No. of edges in the polygon; Perimeter and Area of the polygon; Type of Polygon (triangle or square or rectangle or parallelogram or circle, etc.).

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The property "polygons_closed" returns an array of shapely polygons. So to get ie. the area, use:

```
for polygon in slice_2D.polygons_closed:
    trimesh.path.polygons.plot_polygon(polygon, show=True)
    print(polygon.area)
```

Comment: Dear Holger, thank you for the answer. This really helped. Is there a way to count the number of edged or vertices of the polygon? I also want to find out the approx type of the polygon (circle or traingle or square etc.). If there is no direct way, I thought of an indirect way, that is to save the polgon (shown in the console) as a .PNG or :JPEG and then use cv2 module to find number of edges. Could you please also explain how can I save the polgon shown in the console as a picture withour any borders (axes)? Thank you.

Comment: What you get in 'polygon' is an instance of the class 'polygon' from the package 'shapely'. I recommend taking a look at it in the debugger. It is very powerful and will have all the information needed such as a list of vertices and the moments of inertia.